# How come domain resolves to another IP?

Tags: web-application, webserver, ip, dns-domain, domain

I tried to ping `http://crashsafari.com` in my CMD:

[image: Output ->]

Right there, it resolves `http://crashsafari.com` to `54.231.48.170` which is
`http://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

**But**,

`http://crashsafari.com` and `http://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` are not the same when I type them in my browser and visit the website.

I want to know what exactly is happening? Where exactly does the problem exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where exactly does the problem exist ?

Nowhere. There is no problem.

With ping you are working only at the network layer and on this layer there is no such thing as a hostname, there are only IP addresses. And `crashsafari.com` has the same IP address as `s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` because this is just an alias (DNS CNAME):

```
$ dig crashsafari.com 
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
crashsafari.com.        59      IN      CNAME   crashsafari.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
crashsafari.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 59 IN CNAME s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 4 IN A      54.231.17.132
```

But when using a browser to access a site you are using the application layer protocol HTTP instead. Within this protocol the hostname is sent by the client (HTTP Host header) and thus different hostnames with the same IP address can be distinguished by the server. A request to `http://crashsafari.com` looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: crashsafari.com
...
```

whereas a request to `http://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
...
```

And based on the Host header the server will use a configuration specific for the given hostname, which makes both sites look different even if they share the same IP address.

Comment: But these two hostnames are not same IP .

Comment: @TilakMadichetti: They are the same IP but a different hostname. In fact `crashsafari.com` is just an alias (CNAME) to `crashsafari.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` which itself is a CNAME to `s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. Using `dig crashsafari.com` will give you this information.

Comment: Oh.. okay Now I get it, just include this part in the answer.Thanks !!